# Java API Equivalent of Sun Object

Tags: java, xml, sun

Running static analysis on my code it was pointed out that I shouldn't use Sun classes and use Java APIs instead.

What would be the correct Java API equivalent of the following code:

```
DeferredElementNSImpl nodes = (DeferredElementNSImpl) node;
Node transactionID = nodes.getElementsByTagName("id").item(0);
```

Where node is of type `org.w3c.dom.Node`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cast node to `org.w3c.dom.Element`.

Answer (score -2):

`org.w3c.dom` is not a Sun class.  It is a w3c class.

The classes they want you to avoid are in packages like `com.sun` or occasionally `sun.something`

The `org.w3c.dom` is the standard api for doing any kind of DOM stuff in Java.  It is not something to be written around.